# GROUP_CONCAT should not include its current value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Current Query I am trying to get names of sibling record by parent UiniqId

```
SELECT 
    `SubApplicants`.`SubAppId` AS `AppId`,
    `SubApplicants`.`SubApplicationId` AS `ApplicationId`,
    `SubApplicants`.`SubFirstName`,
    `SubApplicants`.`SubSurname`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`SubApplicants`.`SubFirstName`,
                ' ',
                `SubApplicants`.`SubSurname`)
        SEPARATOR ', ') AS `SubCoApplicantsNames`
   
FROM
    `SubApplicants`
WHERE
    (`SubApplicants`.`IsSubGuarantor` = 0 )
GROUP BY  `SubApplicants`.`SubApplicationId`
```

Comment: `GROUP BY Applicants.ApplicationId` returns 1 row for each `Applicants.ApplicationId`, so the results that you say that you get are not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "current value"?

Comment: Does the real query have a `JOIN` between applicants and co-applicants?

Comment: @Barmar current value means for id 9 firstname aaa is current value

Comment: @Barmar one application have multiple applicants so need to get other applicants name with same application id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question is not exact as you show the output ("current result") that is not groupped by `ApplicationId` as @forpas also noticed and so it does not represent your real situation. However if I understood you properly you may try this as the code will give you the desired output.

```
SELECT Applicants.Id AS Id, 
    Applicants.ApplicationId AS ApplicationId, 
    Applicants.FirstName, 
    Applicants.Surname, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT (
            Applicants2.FirstName, 
            ' ', 
            Applicants2.Surname
            ) SEPARATOR ', ') AS CoApplicantsNames
FROM Applicants
INNER JOIN Applicants AS Applicants2 ON Applicants.ApplicationId = Applicants2.ApplicationID
WHERE Applicants.FirstName != Applicants2.FirstName
    OR Applicants.Surname != Applicants2.Surname
GROUP BY Applicants2.ApplicationId;
```

The first `FROM` will give you the lust of all possible applications and applicants. You may additionally filter it as you wish (for instance `(Applicants.IsGuarantor = 0 )` . The joined table will provide you the last group-concatinated field of co-applicants.

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? You only use that if the second table might have non-matching rows, but that can't happen with this self-join.

Comment: @Barmar you are right. I edited the answer. However in the this case the result will be same.